# why does ptrdiff_t return a nomal difference digit with i - j if i > j and returns a large unrelated number if i < j

Tags: c

```
printf("%td",i-j); when `*i > *j`  the type of both `i` and `j` is `int`
```

if we take,
   `i = &a;`
   `j = &b;`

we would get a normal integer difference, i.e. 42-23 = 19

But if we use this code,

```
printf("%td\n",i- j);   if `*i < *j`
```

with the same scenario, the answer is an unrelated integer. Why?

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bfc5N5SMVvgDzHlc). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You cannot compare pointers pointing to two unrelated objects - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584416/c-compare-pointers

Comment: @Holt Detail, Code can compare unrelated pointers for equality `== !=`.  But not `> >= <= <`.

Comment: @coderredoc Post the types of `i,j`.  Post a [MCVE].  Why say "the answer is an unrelated integer" and not also post the value of that "unrelated integer"?

Comment: @chux  I updated the question

Comment: If `i,j` are `int`, what does the comment `*i > *j` mean?  Better to post code that compiles and demonstrates the problem, rather than simple snippets of code - they are not clear enough.

Comment: typo, I meant i and j are unsigned integers

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

Pointer arithmetic, including the evaluation of the difference between two pointers, is only defined within arrays (one past the end of the array is included and for this purpose an object that is not an element of an array is considered to be a single element array).

Your format specifier `%td` **is** the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Per **6.5.6 Additive operators**, paragraph 9 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of
> the same array object, or  one  past  the  last  element  of  the
> array  object** ...

Therefore, your results are undefined behavior.

Comment: Do mention that "for this purpose a scalar is considered to be a single element array", or something on those lines anyway.

Comment: @Bathsheba Paragraph 7 of 6.5.6?  "For the  purposes  of  these  operators,  a  pointer  to  an  object  that  is  not  an  element  of  an
array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
type of the object as its element type."?  I'm not seeing how that applies here.

Comment: That's the one. It's just that you've answered on the "standard route", and it's nice to have such answers comprehensive.